# ImageMagick on MacOS 10.10 Yosemite - dyld errors

Tags: php, imagemagick, osx-yosemite, dyld

I get the following error when trying to set the path to the imagemagick binary in Drupal (7.31):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
/usr/local/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
```

I've tried unlinking, reinstalling and relinking but to no avail. Also installed php55 using brew and added imagick via pecl but no joy.

The convert binary works fine on the command line, so could be a php config error, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Permissions on the referenced file are lrwxr-xr-x. ls -al gives:

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 <username>  wheel    46B 21 Oct 19:15 /usr/local/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib -> ../Cellar/little-cms2/2.6/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib`

Help?

Comment: what are the permissions on the library?

Comment: examine the extended attributes too (specifically for `com.apple.quarantine`)

Comment: well, error 13 is a permission denied error: `#define EACCES 13 /* Permission denied */` so something on that library isnt right. did you check with `xattr` like i suggested? what user does drupal run as?

Comment: There are no extended attributes on the file. I changed the apache user to my own account and am no longer getting this error.

Comment: sounds like the apache user doesnt have permission to access one of the directories in the path.